# Reading text line by line in a batch file with using psexec and wmic

Tags: batch-file, psexec, wmic

I have test.txt file as below like all ip. (example:)

> 192.168.xxx.50
>
> 192.168.xxx.51
>
> 192.168.xxx.52
>
> 192.168.xxx.53
>
> 192.168.xxx.54
>
> 192.168.xxx.55

I want to make batch file with using psexec, wmic by those IP

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=," %%i in (test.txt) do (
psexec \\<i dont know how to do in here..it should be ip in here each line>-u <domain>\administrator -p <password> wmic /output:\\<serverip should be here which is going to save>\d$\%(i want this each ip info)%.txt product get name,vendor
)
```

how to do..? i think i don't know about  %%parameter

Comment: it's just `%%i`: `psexec \\%%i -u <domain>....`

Answer (score 1):

Wmic can do this without PSExec help. Your file is in correct format for wmic.

```
wmic /node:@"Computerlist.txt" product get name,vendor /format:htable
```

See `wmic /node /?` and `wmic /format /?`.

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and 
choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking 
in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). Type for table format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:htable
```

or in a form format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:hform
```

It will create a html file on the desktop.

**Note**

This is not a full list. This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

or in a file

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUninstall.txt"
```

To see it in notepad in a different format

Click Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type Regedit and navigate to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Right click the Uninstall key and choose Export. If you save as a reg file (there is also text file, they are slightly different text formats) you need to right click the file and choose Edit to view it.

**To view Windows Updates**

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUpdate.html" qfe  get /format:htable
```

Comment: yes i know but some of PC can not work with just only wmic (like permission problem. so i used both it works.) i want to make this by batchfile. but i dont know how to make coding... i just want to put and read test.txt for ip (want to put each ip) on batchfile.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%A in (c:\somefolder\file.ext) do Echo %%A`

Comment: it works on command "psexec \\ip -u domain\administrator -p password cmd wmic /output:\\serverip\%userprofile%.txt product get name,vendor"  but i made batch file like that "for /f "delims=" %%A in (C:\test\test.txt) do psexec \\%%A -u domain\administrator -p password cmd wmic /output:\\serverip\%userprofile%.txt product get name,vendor"  it doesn't work. error message: can not find c:\test\test.txt even there is .